# Checking whether a number is a power of two

Tags: python, math

I am trying to solve the problem 'Power of Two' on Leetcode.

My idea is that for n>=2 to be a power of two, two must divide n and n must not be divisible by any prime 2<= p<= sqrt(n). So first check if n is divisible by two, if not, then it isn't a power of two. If it is divisible, find the primes 2<= p<= sqrt(n) and check if any of them divide n, if at least one does, it isn't a power of two, if none do then n is a power of two.

This was my code.

```
class Solution:
    def isPowerOfTwo(self, n: int) -> bool:
        if n == 1:
            return True
        else:
            if n % 2 != 0:
                return False
            else:
                for i in range(3, round(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
                    for j in range(2, round(math.sqrt(i)) + 1):
                        if i % j == 0:
                            break
                        else:
                            continue
                    if n % i == 0:
                        return False
                    else:
                        continue
                return True
```

I understand this is most likely not the most effective way to solve this problem but I'd like to understand where my code has gone wrong. For example, n = 16 returns False when it should return True.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not find the bug for you here; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre].

Answer (score 6):

@Chris nicely explained the issues with you code.

If you want another approach you can use binary logic:

```
def isPowerOfTwo(n):
    return n > 0 and (n & (n-1) == 0)

for i in range(100000):
    if isPowerOfTwo(i):
        print(i, end=' ')
```

Output:

```
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 2048 4096 8192 16384 32768 65536
```

##### How does it work?

A power of 2 as binary number is represented by a single `1` and the rest as `0`s. Subtracting `1` will necessary produce a number which won't have `1` on the same bit, thus the boolean `&` will give `0`.

Example:

```
# 16    00010000
# 15    00001111
# 16&15 00000000 -> 0

# 18    00010010
# 17    00010001
# 18&17 00010000 -> not 0
```

Answer (score 3):

If we follow a sample of running your function:

```
isPowerOfTwo(32)
```

`32` isn't 1 and it *is* divisible evenly by 2, so we get to the second `else` branch. Rounding the square root of 32 gives us 6, so we iterate with `i` being from 3 to 6. Within that loop we have another loop, but it doesn't really do anything except either break out of itself or continue.

We then test of our input number is evenly divisible by `i`. Since our range will include 4, and 32 is evenly divisible by 4, the function erroneously returns False.

Your issue lies in thinking that the `break` and `continue` will affect the *outer* loop.

You could modify your existing approach by breaking the check to determine if a number is a prime<sup>1</sup> out into a separate function.

### A Simpler Approach

I would suggest a simpler way of thinking about this problem.

You're correct in that 1 is a power of everything. If the number isn't 1, then while it's larger than the base, check if it's evenly divisible by the base. If not, obviously it can't be a power of the base and we can immediately return false.

Otherwise, divide the number by the base.

Continue this until the number is not greater than the base. If at the end, the number is equal to the base, it is a power of that base.

```
is_power_of(32, 2)
32 % 2 == 0, so continue
16 % 2 == 0, so continue
 8 % 2 == 0, so continue
 4 % 2 == 0, so continue
 2 % 2 == 0, and the loop ends
2 == 2, so return True

is_power_of(28, 2)
28 % 2 == 0, so continue
14 % 2 == 0, so continue
 7 % 2 != 0, so return False
```

```
>>> def is_power_of(n, b):
...   if n == 1: return True
...   while n > b: 
...     if n % b != 0: return False
...     n //= b
...   return n == b
... 
>>> is_power_of(16, 2)
True
>>> is_power_of(17, 2)
False
>>> is_power_of(32, 2)
True
>>> is_power_of(28, 2)
False
>>> is_power_of(27, 3)
True
```

---

<sup>1</sup> If you are going to use primes, You should investigate the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: It's cheaper to wind up from 1 rather than down from n. `x = 1; while x <= n {return true if x == n; x *= b;} return false;`

Comment: Does this hold true for something like `2 ** 54 + 1` where division would return false on the first iteration, while multiplication requires 50+ iterations?

Answer (score 0):

Your loops are not quite right. Running your code returns the following list of numbers:

```
1 2 4 6 8 10 14 ...
```

If we consider the first incorrect value, what does your outer loop do?

```
>>> range(3, round(math.sqrt(6)) + 1)
range(3, 3)
```

This will immediately cause the outer loop to break and the function returns True.

An alternative solution is to use logarithms:

```
import math

def isPowerOfTwo(n):
    if n == 0: return False
    f = math.log(n) / math.log(2)
    return f == int(f)
```

Comment: Your code claims that `2**29` isn't a power of 2.